# Knockout or other JavaScript to add/remove properties from an object

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to build a HTML page that allows the user to construct an object that can then be posted as JSON to an internally hosted service (similar to the Chrome Advanced Rest Client). The user must be able to add and remove properties.

My model is not correct because each property is treated like an object with the properties 'name' and 'value'. I end up with an array of objects instead of an object with properties.

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property Name</th>
                <th>Property Value</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>            
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: myFieldList">
            <tr>
                <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: value" /></td>
                <td><span class="removeVar" data-bind="click: removeProperty">Remove property</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <span id="addVar" data-bind="click: addProperty">Add Property</span>
    </p>
<textarea name="tasks" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(myFieldList)"></textarea>
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function dynamicProperty(name, value) {
        var self = this;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    function fieldModel() {
        var self = this;           
//start with 2 empty properties
        self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([
            new dynamicProperty("", ""),
            new dynamicProperty("","")
        ]);

        var noTracker = self.myFieldList.length;

        self.removeProperty = function (dynamicProperty) {
            self.myFieldList.remove(dynamicProperty);
        }

        self.addProperty = function () {
            noTracker++;
            self.myFieldList.push(new dynamicProperty(this.name,this.value));
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(fieldModel);

</script>
```

What I get in the textarea is output like this:

```
[{"name":"test name 1","value":"test value 1"},{"name":"test name 2","value":"test value 2"}]
```

What I want is output like this:

```
{"test name 1":"test value 1","test name 2":"test value 2"}
```

I fear this is rather trivial but in my defense I am very new to JS and Knockout, so any help you can offer would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do something like this to get it done . 
Example : https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/79/

HTML

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property Name</th>
                <th>Property Value</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>            
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: myFieldList">
            <tr>
                <td><input data-bind="textInput: name" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="textInput: value" /></td>
                <td><span class="removeVar" data-bind="click: removeProperty">Remove property</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <span id="addVar" data-bind="click: addProperty">Add Property</span>
    </p>
<textarea name="tasks" data-bind="value: myFieldList2"></textarea>
```

JS

```
function dynamicProperty(name, value) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name || '');
    self.value = ko.observable(value || '');
}

function fieldModel() {
    var self = this; 
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.observable();
    self.myFieldList = ko.observableArray([
        new dynamicProperty("test_name_1", "test value 1"),
        new dynamicProperty("test_name_2","test value 2")
    ]);

    var noTracker = self.myFieldList.length;

    self.myFieldList2 = ko.computed(function () {
       var string = '{';
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.myFieldList(), function (item) {
          string += item.name() + ': ' + item.value() + ',';
       });
       string = string.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
       string+='}';
       return  string;
    });

    self.removeProperty = function (dynamicProperty) {
        self.myFieldList.remove(dynamicProperty);
    }

    self.addProperty = function () {
        noTracker++;
        self.myFieldList.push(new dynamicProperty('',''));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(fieldModel);
```

Comment: Just what I needed. I've modified it slightly to include quotes around the strings - string += '"' + item.name() + '": "' + item.value() + '",'; - and it does just what i want, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a "reducer".

A simple (naive too) implementation would be this:

```
function reduce(input, step, init) {
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    init = step(init, input[i]);
  }

  return init;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
var in = [{"name":"test name 1","value":"test value 1"},{"name":"test name 2","value":"test value 2"}];

var out = reduce(in, function(result, item) {
  result[item.name] = item.value;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

What it does is that it iterates through your array and "accumulates" the result of each step in a single item. Could be the sum of numbers in an array where the "accumulator" would be a number instead of an object.

I advise you don't write your own but instead use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce), it comes with a `_.reduce` function that's optimized.

Comment: There's also a `reduce` in `Array.prototype`. You could use it like so: `dataArray.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    previous[current.name] = current.value;
    return previous;
}, {});` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: You are totally right. IE9+, should be safe to use in most projects.